# Is the directshow runtime library included with the DirectX runtime?

Tags: directshow

I'm writing an activex control that uses direct show to capture and display webcam data.

If the DirectX runtime contains everything for directshow, i won't need to bundle it with the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectShow applications written for Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2) and later do not need to redistribute any DirectShow DLLs.

For Windows XP with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and earlier, redistributable DirectShow DLLs are available from the Microsoft DirectX SDK. The latest version of these DLLs is version 9.0c. No further development of these redistributable DLLs is planned. Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2) contains the version 9.0c DLLs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377592(VS.85).aspx